# how to make merge request in gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab

I can't find the merge request button in this page so how can i make a merge request ? this is the website i am trying to make a merge request for https://gitlab.com/aossie/Agora-web-frontend/merge_requests?scope=all&utf8=%E2%9C%93&state=opened

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FTqn.png)

Comment: It might be that the Agora-web-frontend project is using a [forking workflow](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/authorization_for_merge_requests.html#forking-workflow) where you would  first push to your own fork and initiate the merge request from there to the upstream fork.  I noticed that they also have the [same project](https://github.com/AOSSIE-Org/Agora-web-frontend) on Github, where making a Pull Request from your own fork is very common.

Comment: @TrevorReid yes that's the case thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to first push the branch you've been working on. Then, navigate to that branch, and you should have a "create merge request" button on it.

Comment: i don't have the permissions to make a new branch i had to fork the project then merge my branch . Thanks for your suggestion though